# How to submit a Gremlin query with parameter substitution using TinkerPop API

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I would like to execute the same gremlin statement millions of times, just changing one parameter. The tinkerpop documentation indicates you should be able to use syntax like:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("x",4);
client.submit("[1,2,3,x]", params);
```

My statement is different, but functionally equivalent. It looks like this:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("applicationID", "9b1ef8ce3baabafe5167d276bb07d829")
ResultSet rs = client.submit("g.V().hasLabel('application').has(T.id, applicationID)", params);
```

But I get:

`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: {"detailedMessage":"Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 52, error message : token recognition error at: 'ap'","code":"MalformedQueryException","requestId":"fd0ca287-f81d-4cb8-9a3d-cd2f9d003e3c"}`

It's pretty clearly not liking the parameter name "applicationID"

I've tried enclosing it in quotes, but of course, then it is treated as a string literal.

Comment: Which graph database are you using? Not all of them support query parameterization - mainly as it is not always needed.

Comment: AWS Neptune. Based on your feedback, I examined the stack trace and id DOES seem to be coming from across the wire...checking with Amazon..

Comment: Ahh... answered in their docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#feature-gremlin-differences-variables
Neptune uses the ANTLR grammar in its query processing engine rather than the GremlinGroovyScriptEngine, so it does not support variables or parameterization or the bindings property.

Comment: Yes - that was going to be my follow up comment if you replied Neptune - Amazon Neptune does not compile the scripts. It uses the Antlr grammar for text queries, and has its own custom query planner so does not suffer from issues you can see when using the GremlinGroovyScriptEngine which has to compile the query each time.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported per Amazon's docs:

> [common examples] are usually associated with warnings about performance penalties for not parameterizing when possible. There are a great many such examples for TinkerPop that you may encounter, and they all sound quite convincing about the need to parameterize.
>
> However, both the variables declarations feature and the
> parameterization feature (along with the warnings) only apply to
> TinkerPop's Gremlin Server when it is using the
> GremlinGroovyScriptEngine. They do not apply when Gremlin Server uses
> Gremlin's gremlin-language ANTLR grammar to parse queries. The ANTLR
> grammar doesn't support either variable declarations or
> parameterization, so when using ANTLR, you don't have to worry about
> failing to parameterize. Because the ANTLR grammar is a newer
> component of TinkerPop, older content you may encounter on the
> Internet doesn't generally reflect this distinction.
>
> Neptune uses the ANTLR grammar in its query processing engine rather
> than the GremlinGroovyScriptEngine, so it does not support variables
> or parameterization or the bindings property. As a result, the
> problems related to failing to parameterize do not apply in Neptune.
> Using Neptune, it's perfectly safe simply to submit the query as-is
> where one would normally parameterize.